I completed a transaction on Solana Network but it didn’t show up in my wallet
I had recently bought Kitty via https://raydium.io/swap I can see the successful transaction both on Radium and Solscan but I'm still seeing 0 Kitty in both Trust Wallet and Phantom. Even my Sol too is displays 0 Sol.
The transaction signature is 3ebdvaHHxG8xufe9wbUYyF1WA2UKhGTgSwbeL1CBJbcBzxYWEStfa3BvDusQwDpNvvhEuGZVDrhdvyJRwFfGUPj4


Please check your network.
As you can see, I can see your tokens with phantom wallet with watch account.
It seems that you are off line.

Your account currently contains the tokens

You can also use Solana.fm to verify in the future
solana.fm

I know it's there, I want to transfer it so someone but I can't because I can't access it from wallet.

do you want to provide a screenshot?
